# Give transparent alpha images a flat colour

Tags: materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, transparency, shader-nodes

If i had a scene that included a transparent image mapped to a plane, let's say a leaf for example, and i wanted to remove all shading from that object and make it one flat colour, while also keeping the same alpha channel (transparency) on it, how would i go about doing that? I can nearly achieve the effect i want by using a principled shader with ONLY the alpha input of the transparent image and the diffuse input just set to one colour. the only problem is that its still shaded while i want a flat colour.

the reason i want to do this is since i do alot of post processing and having a render where every object is a unique flat color makes it easier to select various parts of it in photo editing programs.

i'm using Eevee for reference, and thanks in advance and please comment if there is anything i didn't make clear.

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Shader for flat output]

The closest you are going to get to flat *rendered* images requires:

- No lights in your scene
- Set the world shader's color to pure white.
- Set the world shader to the same strength as you use with your emission shaders.
- Use the above shader node group on all of your materials, leaving the strength at 1 but changing the emission color for each material.

Comment: as stated in the question this will not work as i require unshaded flat colour. but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Stagbeetle -- in the above Marty is using the image *only* for the alpha -- where to allow the coloring.   The BSDF is then using a single (flat?) color (purple in this case) for the flat color.

Comment: @Stagbeetle  The whole purpose of a render is to calculate the interaction of light with materials.  You can't accomplish your goal completely, but the above is as close as you will get.

Comment: this new method you showed works pretty well. Thanks! this'll work for my purposes.

Comment: @Stagbeetle You're welcome.  Sorry I didn't fully appreciate what you were trying to do when I wrote the first answer.